# Set buttons on image in specific locations

Tags: android, dictionary, imageview, pixel

I'm trying to crate custom map in my application, the needed map is not Google map, its consists of image and small pins images, in other word its image view,,, i need to set buttons on this image in specific locations, and wen these buttons clicked , i need to perform some action, the problem is i didn't found a way makes me able to set buttons on this image at run time, the image and the buttons locations will be received from the server side, so i need to create this custom map at run time. maybe i need to set the buttons on specific pixels, but i don't know how i can reach specific pixels in the image, i appreciate any help in this. thank you all.